# How to fix the template error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."?

Tags: 2011, templating

I'm facing a random error on .Net templating.

> **There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.**

The above error is occurring when multiple pages are publishing using the .Net template CT.

When I google about this error, I saw many question on Stackoverflow.
Most of the answers are mentioned that

- Set `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` on the connection string

### *Example:*

```
Server=server;Initial Catalog=database;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;....
```

- Connection is not disposed

I don't think that we have facility on configuration to set `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

Please suggest.

### UPDATE:

While code accessing below lines, error encounters.

```
ItemFields itemFields = new ItemFields(RootElement, Schema);

Component.Content
```

This will happen only when multiple pages are published at a time and also, there are multiple places like accessing `keywords description` the same error occurs.

### StackTrace:

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri id, StoredProcedureInvocation spInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetDataObject(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags flags, Boolean forceReload)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Load(LoadFlags flags, Boolean forceReload)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.get_CurrentState()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.get_Content()
   ***
   ***
   ***
```

Hope this will help in understanding the problem.

Comment: Are you using any code to directly interacting with any DBMS, whether Tridion CM/Broker or any other Custom DB?

Comment: @PankajGaur: No direct interaction with database. My code is only for reading components and keywords. Its simple code which refers on different CT's.

Comment: is it possible to share your code?

Comment: @PankajGaur: I have updated the question with few more information.

Comment: All I can think of is indeed a defect in Tridion - but this is a pretty big one, pretty sure it was fixed by now. Check your hotfixes/contact support.

Comment: @NunoLinhares: Thanks Nuno. It looks like issue is causing due to multi-thearding. At the same time, I will check with support about this.

Comment: @Siva Charan: I also got the same error. any one have any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: I think it would really help if you can share a bit of code from your templates which we can use to reproduce the problem. Please edit your question and don't just post two lines of code, but a snipped which makes more sense. While the error may occur on one of those lines, the code around them might give a clue to why the error occurs in the first place

Answer (score 2):

There's quote a bit of information online  when googling this error message, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c

Perhaps sharing your code here will get the answer you are looking for.

thanks

Comment: Thanks john but I already said in the question that to set the connection string with `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`.

Comment: But unfortunately, I am not accessing the database directly to set `MARS` as True.

Comment: I suspect that the tridion DLL's has a bug, sorry if am wrong.

Comment: @SivaCharan - didn't see that :S

Comment: Since I was calling the base functions of tridion nothing else am doing. I don't have any DB related code. DB connection are involved only on tridion DLL's where call will go to DB and get the contents of it.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of effort on debugging and understanding the issue, I came to know that

> Issue looks like causing due to **MULTI-THREADING**.

### How I conclude:

If I set Number of `Rendering` as

1. `1` on MMC Snap-In, there is no error
2. More than `1` on MMC Snap-In, then random errors will encounter.

### How to Fix:

Contact Tridion Support to fix the issue.

Comment: Only if your templates are doing something "weird". I never had trouble with multiple tender threads

Comment: @NunoLinhares: Sorry Nuno, there is nothing weird code written. When the call tries to access `Itemfields` or `Component.Content`... above mentioned error encounters randomly

Comment: OK. Reason why I say this is that I never had problems with using multi-threaded publishers (except in a customer that insisted that writing from templates was an acceptable practice)

Comment: Not shure how to read this as an answer, you mention: "it looks like a multi threading issue", so you are not sure, which means this is not an answer? You end with: "how to fix; contact customer support", so you haven't found an answer? If both of these conslusions are true, I suggest you delete this answer and edit your question and add this information in your question. An answer should contain a solution, and not a suggestion to contact customer support (unless the suggestion is to contact CS for a certain hotfix, in which case you can mention what fix that is, so others can do the same).

Answer (score -2):

This was able to help to resolve this problem:

```
 <connectionStrings>
     <add name="myconnConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=000.000.0.00;Initial Catalog=dbname;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=sguser;Password=mypass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
```